# How to call a Jquery automatically after a Div is created?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

I need some help here. I am trying to get Highchart to load (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/your-first-chart). The sample chart loads properly when the div already exist in my index.html.

However, the div for the highchart will be created on the fly whenever a button is created.

```
function querySomething {
//I have an popup that is able to display html code onto itself. So here "out" contains the html code to be sent to the popup.
var out = "";

out = out + "START OF CHART";
out = out + "<div id='chart' style='width:100%; height:100px;'></div>";
out = out + "END OF CHART";

//process and display the html in "out" here
}
```

So below in the same javascript file, I put what the webpage gave:

```
$(function () { 
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
```

});

However, when I access the popup, all I see is a huge blank between my start and end:

```
START OF CHART







END OF CHART
```

I think it is because the jquery is called when the page load, but the div is not created yet. I googled and found out about the on() method.

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

So I tried:

```
$('body').on('click', '#chart', function () { 
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});
```

However, it still did not work. Also, The event is not supposed to be on click but to automatically display the chart as soon as the div is created. Any help please?

EDIT: I changed to event to "change" like so:

```
    $('body').on('change', '#chart', function () { 
$('#chart').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [1, 0, 4]
    }, {
        name: 'John',
        data: [5, 7, 3]
    }]
});
});
```

But still get a blank chart div.

Comment: try ...on('change'... and bind event to chart so
$('#chart').on('change', function() {...

Comment: could you provide your html markup also? better, post your attempts on jsfiddle.net and link it in your question...
the reason of this issue is, that js is binded only to those elements of the dom, that are already there. 
workaround would be, to bind it to a wrapper element, that already exists ...

Comment: @SwaghettiYolonese thanks for your quick reply! I tried it but nothing changed.

Comment: @errand I am working on an ArcGis map and the map has a inbuilt popup window so that's where I am putting the highchart div. The map is provided and all I need to do is to load the map and put in a simpel <div id = "map"></div> and the map will appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The div you created has the id = 'chart'

```
out = out + "<div id='chart' style='width:100%; height:100px;'></div>";
```

whereas the container id you're passing to highcharts is 'container'

```
$('#container').highcharts({
```

and to check whether div is created at the time of highcharts call, you can try:

```
alert(document.getElementById('chart'));
```

if it shows an element it means the div is already created. If not then you can try:

```
$('#chart').on('change', function() {
```

Just to be sure, you can also try:

```
$(document).ready(function() { /* code here */ });
```

Comment: Naming isn't the problem because I did used #chart. The #container you saw was because I was referencing the highchart webpage. Where should I put the alert(document.getElementById('chart')); ? I have tried $('#chart').on('change', function() { but it still didnt display anything

Comment: put it before $('#chart').highcharts({

Comment: There was no alert at all. Is it because this jquery was fired before my chart div was created? (the chart div will only be created when I click on a point on my map and the pop up window appears)

Comment: why don't you put this highcharts code in a function and call it when you click on that point on map?

Comment: ok I tried that and I called the function right below my out = out + "<div id='chart' style='width:100%; height:100px;'></div>"; I also put an alert(document.getElementById('chart')); and I get a null. Maybe it's something wrong with the popup window..

Comment: show the code where you're calling the pop up and writing that div and chart start end onto it

Comment: omg ok I made a silly mistake. What I was doing was just creating the HTML code as a string and storing it into my out variable. I have not actually ran the html code. The chart works after I placed the function calling below the actual HTML display!! Thanks Jabbar! I'm ticking this as this helped guide me to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could use a callback function that executes after the function that creates DIV is compleated.

In callback function add the code that populates the DIV.